# UIPageViewController frame gets stretched in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

So I have a UITableView with 20 cells in it. I am not reusing cells, every cell is its own thing. I am trying insert a UIPageViewController within the UITableViewCell HOWEVER! when I set the frame size to say CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) the frame height gets really stretched in the cell.

I think the issue occurs when I use a ViewControllers view in the cell. Otherwise when I declare a normal view the size is fine.

The issue occurs on both simulator and the device. 
Please help!.

Once again the issue is happening for me when I try to post some type of [ViewController].view. My final goal is to add a PageViewController to a UITableViewCell, but the height of the controller gets really stretched.

```
UIViewController * v = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
v.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
v.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[cell addSubview:v.view];
```

Comment: try to add on cell.contentView

Answer (score 0):

I think that UIView is what you are looking for not UIViewController:

```
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
```

Comment: I am actually looking to use a UIPageViewController inside of a UITableviewCell. Like I said in my post the UIView looks fine in the cell, however when I post the view of a UIViewController then the views height is super stretched.